# How to display or show all tables in a mysql database into html table with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that creates tables with 3 rows in the admin's database(users).

```
$sql1="CREATE TABLE '".$username."' (id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT, ip VARCHAR(255), password VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (id))";
```

So I want to have all the tables (it's rows and data) in the users database displayed on admin's dashboard like this:

```
<h3>Table_Name</h3>
<tr>
<th>Row1</th><th>Row2</th><th>Row3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>All Data On Row1</td><td>All Data On Row2</td><td>All Data On Row3</td>
</tr>
```

Please someone should help me with a tested php mysql query on this issue. I sincerely don't have an idea on how to make this work. My xamp isn't helping matters because it can't seem to connect with the database, so i find it difficult testing my code; so help me with a tested and working code.

Comment: How do you connect to your database?

Comment: And I think you mean 3 columns, not 3 rows

Comment: Note that the number in parentheses after an INT is almost meaningless in MySQL (as well as being a really odd constraint to wish to try to impose upon oneself)

Comment: It's also REALLY odd to create separate tables for each user

Comment: Am working on creating a database that keeps clients access to our pricing table, and there are some other columns i did not add like price bargain. So they reason am creating a separate table is so that clients can insert different price each time the access the system. So the system stores all there pricing in their table at different times.

Answer (score 0):

1. First select a database.
2. to get all tables of the database, run this query `show TABLES;`
3. To get all column names of a table run this query `DESCRIBE your_table_name;`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you display the data display from database into the HTML tables

1. create a database connection

   ```
   $dbCon= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","test");
   if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
       echo "Failed to connect: ". mysqli_connect_errno();
   }

   ?>
   ```

Then in your php file where you want to show the data in the form of tables

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>IP.</th>
        <th>Password</th>        
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php
  require("connection.php");
  $query="SELECT * FROM your_table_name ";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbCon, $query)or die(mysqli_error($dbCon));
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  {
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['ip']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If you have more data to show just add the column name.

Comment: Please what i want to display is not just one table, but all the table that are automatically generated by my php code on the database. What you pasted here is how to display details from a table, but what i want is how to display all tables with their content in the database. I want it to display automatically on admin dashboard when a new user enters the system.

Comment: Can you be more specific what exactly you are trying to achieve